# Populate the dropdown based on date selected

Tags: jquery

I am trying to populate the dropdown based on date selected.. When user selects sunday (6:00 am,7 am) has to be displayed and when user selects weekdays (2:00 am) has to be displayed Here is the code.. My code displays 1,2,3,4,5 when sunday is selected and when other day it is selected data appended doesnt gets cleared

Here is the code

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("#txtDate").change(function() {
       var numbers = [6:00 am, 2:am];
       
    var selDate = new Date(this.value);
    var option = '';
    if (selDate.getDay() == 0) { //If sunday, can change your logic here
  

for (var i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
   option += '<option value="'+ numbers[i] + '">' + numbers[i] + '</option>';
   
}

$('#items').append(option);
  } else {
      $(".form-control").val(300);
    }
  })
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your numbers array contains variables that are not declared correctly, and are not numbers.

Comment: Why was this tagged with PHP when it's 100% js?

Answer (score 0):

Please replace,
var numbers = [6:00 am, 2:am];
with
var numbers = ['6:00 am', '2:am'];